# Is it possible to calculate the size of an xml if it is loaded into XmlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to find out if there is a way to calculate the file size from XmlReader. I don't see anything on the reader object that helps determine the size. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
Using reader As Xml.XmlReader = GetXML(columnName.ToString())

End Using
```

Comment: What is your reason for needing to know the size? That might help find a workaround.

Comment: It is just for displaying to the user for some purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlReader` might not read from something that has a known or definite size. Your best bet would be to do something with the source of whatever the `XmlReader` is reading. E.g. you might have a `Stream` and try to get [`Stream.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (some streams don't support this, as they don't have a length). This will require modifying `GetXML`.

Comment: Also, not all streams have a length.

Comment: @JohnSaunders good point. The documentation shows that `Length` might throw, but it's good to note that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use XmlReader as your source, this should get you close to the file size (c#):

```
int sizeInBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ReadOuterXml()).Length;
```

Comment: Yes, I must use the XmlReader. Thank you. I will try it out.